# No updates from the 11.04 natty repositories since 30th of April?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

Since the release of 11.04, I haven't received any updates from the repositories for 11.04.I installed the beta version, and as far as I've understood I'm currently running on the released version.

I can't really believe there hasn't been a single patch or update since 30th of April.

Answer (score 2):

There have been updates, ensure that these checkboxes are checked in your Software Sources:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, enabled those checkboxes and voilà 250MB++ worth of updates.

Comment: @MrJavalava Mark the question as answered by pressing the checkmark sign to the left of the post that helped you. Also see the [faq](http://askubuntu.com/faq) for more info regarding asking and answering questions.

Answer (score 0):

There has been many updates since the release, try manually checking for updates by going to the terminal and using the following command.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Yeah, I've run the updates manually with the same result. It must be the repositories.